# How do I restart Apache Tomcat server using web application button?

Tags: javascript, windows, apache, batch-file, tomcat7

I need to implement in front-end (JavaScript) button which will allow to restart Apache Tomcat server running this web application (MS Win).

From Windows cmd line it is quite simple (...)\apache\bin\start.bat (...)\apache\bin\stop.bat is enough to restart this single instance of Apache.

How to handle it from web site level ( permission of using this button will be handle on application level).

Comment: and web application is running on different server right?

Comment: No it is running on this server. I'm aware that after pushing this button server won't be avaliable for some time. After server will start up and user will be able to log in again.